# How to create a Firewall rule for Compute Engine via Google Cloud Client?

Tags: google-api, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-api-client, google-api-java-client

I am currently using the Java Google Cloud Client for Compute Engine. I was able to successfully create a Network. Is it possible to programatically create a new firewall rule (given source, protocol, port, tags, etc)? It seems this is possible using gcloud command line, but I'd like to know how to do this via API. I've looked through all of the documentation but can't seem to find anything related to this. In addition, how can I tie the firewall rule to a specific Network? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sure, see the API reference, at the bottom it has examples for a variety of languages:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/firewalls/insert

Note that if we can do something with gcloud, we can always do it with REST API (and its language bindings), gcloud is just a command line wrapper for the API. If you add --log-http flag in the command, it will show you the HTTP details.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping that there would be an easy to use API from the java google client. I'm using this http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.3.0/apidocs/ . The API doc doesn't seem to have anything on creating firewall or handling SSH keys :(

Thanks for the flag to see HTTP details. I suppose I'll need to do some manual REST calls.